# When I am putting to .draw a circle in the middle of my window I get an error

Tags: python, pygame

this is the code
note: the code has some stuff I have yet to implement.
I am using pygame to make a scrolling game and am trying to get the basics down.

```
import pygame

class Player:

    def __init__(self, x, y, size):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.jumping = False
        self.jump_offset = 0


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = 0
W = 1280
H = 720
HW = W / 2
HH = H / 2

win = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 30
pygame.display.set_caption('if the shoe fits wear it')

p = Player(HW, HH, 30)
jump_height = 50

running = True
while running:
    pygame.draw.circle(win, WHITE, ((p.x, p.y)), p.size, BLACK)#problem
    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

this is the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/pygame/jump.py", line 34, in <module>
pygame.draw.circle(win, WHITE, ((p.x, p.y)), p.size, BLACK)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Process finished with exit code 1
```

integer argument expected, got float

Comment: One of the arguments to `pygame.draw.circle` is a `float`, and it is expecting an `int`.  Try printing the types of each argument or stepping through your code with a debugger to see which argument is the problem.  (I would put money on `p.x` or `p.y`).

Comment: Ok, so did you read the error message? What don't you understand?

Comment: Also: Your code has an indent error with `running=True`

Answer (score 1):

In pygame, any arguments that refer to pixels should be of type `int`, not `float`. You can fix this by changing `HW` and `HH`:

```
HW = W // 2
HH = H // 2
```

The `/` operator always returns a float. The `//` operator gives you an `int` if both operands are `int`s.